# Access AWS Secret inside docker file

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, dockerfile, secret-management

I have a docker file running on AWS that looks like the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN git init
RUN git clone https://<HARDCODED-ACCESS-TOKEN>@github.com/<folder>/<repo>.git ./new_folder
```

I have created an AWS secret "git_access_secret" that contains my access token and I would like to access it in my dockerFile so I could do something that looks roughly like the following:

```
RUN git clone https://secrets[git_access_secret]@github.com/<folder>/<repo>.git ./new_folder
```

How is this possible to achieve?